# Terminal based "Connect 4" game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, connect-four

I started learning Python a few weeks ago and coded this "Connect 4" game.

What could I have done better? How efficient is this code and how could I improve on that?

```
from collections import defaultdict
from termcolor import colored
from time import sleep

class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.symbol = 0
        # board MAIN horizontal
        self.row1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.row2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.row3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.row4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.row5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.row6 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.board_state_row = []
        self.board_state_collumn = []
        self.board_state_diagonal = []

    def drop_stones(self):
        l1 = [i for i, v in enumerate(self.row2) if v == 0]
        for i in l1:
            self.row2[i] = self.row1[i]
            self.row1[i] = 0
        l2 = [i for i, v in enumerate(self.row3) if v == 0]
        for i in l2:
            self.row3[i] = self.row2[i]
            self.row2[i] = 0
        l3 = [i for i, v in enumerate(self.row4) if v == 0]
        for i in l3:
            self.row4[i] = self.row3[i]
            self.row3[i] = 0
        l4 = [i for i, v in enumerate(self.row5) if v == 0]
        for i in l4:
            self.row5[i] = self.row4[i]
            self.row4[i] = 0
        l5 = [i for i, v in enumerate(self.row6) if v == 0]
        for i in l5:
            self.row6[i] = self.row5[i]
            self.row5[i] = 0

    def update(self):
        # board horizontal
        self.board_state_row = [self.row1, self.row2, self.row3, self.row4, self.row5, self.row6]
        # board vertical
        self.board_state_collumn = []
        for i in range(0, 7, 1):
            self.board_state_collumn.append(self.rows_to_collumns(i))
        # board diagonal
        rows = 6
        collumns = 7
        diagonal1 = defaultdict(list)  # For the top right to bottom left
        diagonal2 = defaultdict(list)  # For the top left to bottom right
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(collumns):
                diagonal1[i - j].append(self.board_state_row[i][j])
                diagonal2[i + j].append(self.board_state_row[i][j])
        self.board_state_diagonal = []
        self.board_state_diagonal.insert(0, diagonal1)
        self.board_state_diagonal.insert(1, diagonal2)

    def make_turn(self, slot, activeplayer):
        if activeplayer == 1:
            self.symbol = 1
        if activeplayer == 2:
            self.symbol = -1
        if slot in range(0, 7):
            self.row1[slot] = self.symbol
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def print_board(self):

        print(
            ' 1 ', ' | ',
            ' 2 ', ' | ',
            ' 3 ', ' | ',
            ' 4 ', ' | ',
            ' 5 ', ' | ',
            ' 6 ', ' | ',
            ' 7 ', ' | ',)

        # row1
        print(
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[0]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[1]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[2]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[3]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[4]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[5]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row1[6]), ' | ')

        # row2
        print(
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[0]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[1]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[2]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[3]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[4]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[5]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row2[6]), ' | ')

        # row3
        print(
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[0]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[1]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[2]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[3]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[4]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[5]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row3[6]), ' | ')

        # row4
        print(
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[0]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[1]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[2]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[3]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[4]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[5]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row4[6]), ' | ')

        # row5
        print(
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[0]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[1]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[2]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[3]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[4]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[5]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row5[6]), ' | ')

        # row6
        print(
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[0]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[1]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[2]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[3]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[4]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[5]), ' | ',
            self.state_to_sign(self.row6[6]), ' | ')

    def rows_to_collumns(self, index):
        collumn = []
        for i in self.board_state_row:
            collumn.append(i[index])
        return collumn

    def check_win_horizontal(self):
        for i in range(0, 6, 1):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_row[i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True
                    else:
                        wincounter = 0

    def check_win_vertical(self):
        for i in range(0, 7, 1):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_collumn[i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True

    def check_win_diagonal(self):
        for i in range(-6, 5, 1):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_diagonal[0][i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True
                    else:
                        wincounter = 0

        for i in range(0, 11, 1):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_diagonal[1][i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True
                    else:
                        wincounter = 0

    @staticmethod
    def state_to_sign(state):
        if state == 1:
            return colored(' @ ','red')
        if state == -1:
            return colored(' @ ','yellow')
        if state == 0:
            return '   '


class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_number):
        self.name = 'default'
        self.player_number = player_number

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name


def start_game():
    player1 = Player(1)
    player2 = Player(2)
    board = Board()

    player1.set_name(input('Whats your name Player1?: '))
    player2.set_name(input('Whats your name Player2?: '))

    activeplayer = 1
    while activeplayer > 0:
        try:
            board.drop_stones()

            while activeplayer == 1:
                board.print_board()
                slot = int(input('Which slot do you choose ' + player1.name + '? 1-7 or 0 to exit: '))
                if slot == 0:
                    exit()
                if slot > 0:
                    slot = slot - 1
                    if board.row1[slot] != 0:
                        print('Slot full! Pick another one 1-7: ')
                        break
                    board.make_turn(slot, activeplayer)
                    board.update()
                    board.drop_stones()
                    board.update()
                    if board.check_win_diagonal() or board.check_win_horizontal() or board.check_win_vertical():
                        board.print_board()
                        print('you win', player1.name + '!')
                        activeplayer = 0
                    if not board.check_win_diagonal() \
                            and not board.check_win_horizontal() \
                            and not board.check_win_vertical():
                        activeplayer = 2
                else:
                    print('Out of range! 1-7: ')
                    break

            while activeplayer == 2:
                board.print_board()
                slot = int(input('Which slot do you choose ' + player2.name + '? 1-7 or 0 to exit: '))
                if slot == 0:
                    exit()
                if slot > 0:
                    slot = slot - 1
                    if board.row1[slot] != 0:
                        print('Slot full! Pick another one 1-7: ')
                        break
                    board.make_turn(slot, activeplayer)
                    board.update()
                    board.drop_stones()
                    board.update()
                    if board.check_win_diagonal() or board.check_win_horizontal() or board.check_win_vertical():
                        board.print_board()
                        print('you win', player2.name + '!')
                        activeplayer = 0
                    if not board.check_win_diagonal() \
                            and not board.check_win_horizontal() \
                            and not board.check_win_vertical():
                        activeplayer = 1
                else:
                    print('Out of range! 1-7: ')
                    break

        except IndexError:
            print('Out of range... 1-7! ')
        except ValueError:
            print('Only numbers! 1-7: ')

    sleep(1.5)


start_game()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues with your code. I will try to cover all of them.

### Logic Repetiton

- In your `start_game()` function, you are repeating the almost same loop for both players.

You can make a `current_player` and use it instead of `player1` or `player2`.

- You can just use a `else` statement in this piece of code -

```
if board.check_win_diagonal() or board.check_win_horizontal() or 
          board.check_win_vertical():
    ...
if not board.check_win_diagonal() \
        and not board.check_win_horizontal() \
        and not board.check_win_vertical():
    activeplayer = 1
```

Instead -

```
if board.check_win_diagonal() or board.check_win_horizontal() or 
          board.check_win_vertical():
    ...
else:
    activeplayer = 1
```

### Unnecessary objects

- I would prefer to use a `grid` variable storing all the rows rather than making each row a seperate variable. Then you can iterate over each row with a `loop`.
- Your class `Player` does not do much. You could just use `player1` and `player2` variables.
  Also you are never using `Player.player_number`.

### Print board function

- You can make your function shorter by using a `for loop`.

```
def print_board(self):
    print('|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |')
        for row in self.grid:
            print('|  ', end='')
            for index in range(7):
                print(str(self.state_to_sign(row[index])) + '|  ', end='')
            print('')
```

### Ignoring Performance

- Your `drop_stones()` function checks all columns. This affects the performance. Instead check only the column chosen by the user.

### Other improvements(do not matter much)

- By default the step parameter of range is 1. You do not need to specify it.
  `range(1, 10)` instead of `range(1, 10, 1)`.

**Happy Coding!**

## Edit:

**This is the review for the optimized code posted again by OP.**

### Coupling

"How easy is it to cut out a piece of code?" If the answer is "very difficult" then our system is likely tightly coupled. Ideally, it is easy to remove code (say we find it doesn't work as intended and need to replace it) and it is easy to run that cut out code by itself (say we want to test it).

Most of the functions look good. There are some that could be improved.

```
def check_tie(self):
    if 0 not in self.board_state_row[0]:
        print('You tied! No one Wins!')
        sleep(1.5)
        exit()
```

What if you wanted to test this function?(I know its very simple function)

You wont be able to check it multiple times because it will end the program.

You want to only return if its a tie or not and do the necessary outside the function.

```
def check_tie(self):
    return 0 not in self.board_state_row[0]
```

Credit for the explanation to [spyr03](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58248/spyr03)

### List Comprehension

- When ever you can, you should use a list comprehension as it almost always faster than for loops.
  So you can upgrade your `columns_to_rows()` accordingly.

### if **name** == '**main**'

- You should always use `if __name__ == '__main__'` in your files.

You should wrap your all all your `while active_player > 0` code in a function `play()` and then use it under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

You can read more about it on this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/16246688).

### F Strings

- You can use `f-strings` from `Python 3.6`. `f-strings` are simply faster than `%s` and `str.format()`.

### Other Improvement

- In this piece of code:

```
if active_player == 1:
    return int(2)
if active_player == 2:
    return int(1)
```

You can just return `active_player`.

- When defining matrices, it is nice to define it like this:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

It also is easier to understand its structure.

- You can use the `+=` operator to perform some of your calculations.

Example - `a = a + 1` is same as `a += 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will look into everything you mentioned and try to improve things :)

Answer (score 2):

Cool program!

Computers are machines for automation; any time you find your code is repetitive, like in `print_board` or the two players in `start_game`, it's very likely you can make the code shorter by using an array or a function.

A few other odds and ends:

- The `try` block in `start_game` is quite long, and catches `IndexError` and `ValueError`, errors that very often indicate a bug. So if there is a bug in any of that code that causes an IndexError, the program would just print "`Out of range... 1-7!`" and keep going. The error message would be lost.
- It's considered good style in Python to separate words in variable names with `_`, so `active_player` rather than `activeplayer`.
- It's also considered good style for a method like `check_win_horizontal` to `return False` at the end, so that it always returns either `True` or `False`. If you don't return anything at the end of a function, Python returns `None` by default, so the program still works. But it's just a little confusing.
- Your program doesn't check for the possibility of a tie game. It's possible to fill up the entire grid without anyone winning.
- The printed board seems to need a `|` and some more space on the left.
- The English word "columns" only has one L in it.

But all of this is very minor. It's a fine program. Hope you're having fun with Python! :)

Answer (score 1):

So finally, with your super helpful tips and after a few hours of improving stuff I got rid of a few lines of code, all the `self.row` variables and improved some of the functions. Also I got rid of the `Player` class since it was only storing the names, which I implemented as variables now.

The `drop_stones` and `print_board` methods are also much less code now and `drop_stones` now uses the selected column instead of every row so it has to check and change only one list instead of a whole 2d list. Next thing on the list would be a function to check for a tie, but I'm sure I need another few hours to come up with a crappy solution for that XD

Edit: I wrote the check_tie function to check for a tie (when the first of the row is full and no one has won). Also I fixed a bug where input was declared as `str` while `int` was needed.

Here is the "optimized" code:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from termcolor import colored
from time import sleep


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.symbol = 0
        self.board_state_row = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
        self.board_state_column = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
        self.board_state_diagonal = []

    def drop_stones(self, slot):
        a = self.board_state_column[slot]
        b = deque([x for x in a if x != 0])
        for i in a:
            if i == 0:
                b.appendleft(0)
        self.board_state_column[slot] = b

    def update(self):
        # board rows
        self.board_state_row = []
        for i in range(6):
            self.board_state_row.append(self.columns_to_rows(i))

        # board diagonals
        rows = 6
        columns = 7
        diagonal1 = defaultdict(list)  # For the top right to bottom left
        diagonal2 = defaultdict(list)  # For the top left to bottom right
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                diagonal1[i - j].append(self.board_state_row[i][j])
                diagonal2[i + j].append(self.board_state_row[i][j])
        self.board_state_diagonal = []
        self.board_state_diagonal.insert(0, diagonal1)
        self.board_state_diagonal.insert(1, diagonal2)

    def make_turn(self, slot, active_player):
        if active_player == 1:
            self.symbol = 1
        if active_player == 2:
            self.symbol = -1
        if slot in range(0, 7):
            self.board_state_column[slot][0] = self.symbol
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def print_board(self):
        for i in range(1,8):
            print(' '+str(i)+' ', ' | ', end= ' ')
        print('')

        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(7):
                print(self.state_to_sign(self.board_state_row[i][j]), ' | ',end=' ')
            print('')

    def columns_to_rows(self, index):
        row = []
        for i in self.board_state_column:
            row.append(i[index])
        return row

    def check_win_horizontal(self):
        for i in range(6):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_row[i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True
                    else:
                        wincounter = 0

        if wincounter == 0:
            return False

    def check_win_vertical(self):
        for i in range(7):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_column[i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True

        if wincounter == 0:
            return False

    def check_win_diagonal(self):
        for i in range(-6, 5):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_diagonal[0][i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True
                    else:
                        wincounter = 0

        for i in range(11):
            wincounter = 0
            for j in self.board_state_diagonal[1][i]:
                if j != self.symbol:
                    wincounter = 0
                if j == self.symbol or wincounter == 0:
                    if j == self.symbol:
                        wincounter = wincounter + 1
                        if wincounter == 4:
                            return True
                    else:
                        wincounter = 0

        if wincounter == 0:
            return False

    def check_tie(self):
        if 0 not in self.board_state_row[0]:
            print('You tied! No one Wins!')
            sleep(1.5)
            exit()

    @staticmethod
    def state_to_sign(state):
        if state == 1:
            return colored(' @ ','red')
        if state == -1:
            return colored(' @ ','yellow')
        if state == 0:
            return '   '


def game(current_player,active_player):
    board.print_board()
    slot = int(input('Which slot do you choose ' + current_player + '? 1-7 or 0 to exit: '))
    if slot == 0:
        exit('Exit by selection.')
    if slot > 0:
        slot = slot - 1
        while board.board_state_row[0][slot] != 0:
            slot = int(input('Slot full! Pick another one 1-7: '))
            slot = slot -1

        board.make_turn(slot, active_player)
        board.update()
        board.drop_stones(slot)
        board.update()
        if board.check_win_diagonal() or board.check_win_horizontal() or board.check_win_vertical():
            board.print_board()
            print('you win '+ current_player + '!')
            sleep(1.5)
            exit(0)
        board.check_tie()
        if active_player == 1:
            return int(2)
        if active_player == 2:
            return int(1)


board = Board()
player1 = input('Whats your name Player1?: ')
player2 = input('Whats your name Player2?: ')
active_player = 1

while active_player > 0:
    try:
        while active_player == 1:
            active_player = game(player1, active_player)

        while active_player == 2:
            active_player = game(player2, active_player)

    except IndexError:
        print('Out of range... 1-7! ')
    except ValueError:
        print('Only numbers! 1-7: ')
sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: I edited my answer to higlight some issues in your code. Have a look.